# Rendering canvas content in Redux/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, redux

I'm having some trouble rendering the contents of a canvas element when it clearly works outside of React/Redux. Currently it's just a blank, black canvas element.

Here is the code I'm trying to get working:

```
export default class CanvasElement extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderCanvas = this.renderCanvas.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.canvas.width = 220;
    this.canvas.height = 50;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.renderCanvas();
  }

  renderCanvas() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = `hsla(${this.props.hue}, 100%, 90%, 0.5)`;
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 220, 50);
    this.props.updateHue(this.props.hue);
    requestAnimationFrame(this.renderCanvas);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas ref={canvas => {this.canvas = canvas;}} height='50' width='220' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have everything else correctly defined as console logs show `this.props.hue` cycles through the hue rotation (i.e., 0->360->0..).

Comment: What does your `updateCanvas` do?

Comment: It just increments the state's hue property. At `> 360`, the hue resets to `0`. I just changed the name to `updateHue` to be more clear as to what the method does.